# Why does this simple equation lose the (-) sign?

Tags: linear-algebra

$A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 2\\1 & 3\end{bmatrix}$

The solution has a part that states:

$2A - A^t = 2\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2\\1 & 3\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2\\1 & 3\end{bmatrix}^t$

Where does the "$+$" between the two matrices come from? I thought it should have stayed a "$-$".

Thanks

Comment: As written, there seems no reason for this plus sign to appear. So it would seem to be a typo.

Comment: Great, I was worried there was a matrix property I was missing.